# Windows Phone XAML Listbox, Iterate over a collection with a collection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have got here a little problem that I have to solve.
I have a ViewModel with a collection, so this collection holds objects of the type "Category", each Category has a List of "Channels".
So, I want to show the collection of the categories and directly at the bottom the list of all channels for each category.

Some thing like this:

[image]

How to do this in Xaml? With data bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're using the wrong control for this kind of thing.  You should be using a `LongListSelector` since Grouping is already built in.

Here's a working example: [How to display data in a grouped list in LongListSelector for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx)

---

Launch the News Application for the Windows Phone 8 and you can see LongListSelector Group in action.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it before like this, but it not worked! But now it is working this way!

```
 <ListBox x:Name="AllCategoriesList" ItemsSource="{Binding categories}" Margin="10,0">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding channels}" Grid.Row="1">
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```